# How to make IDLE window more readable? Font too small for me to see

Tags: python, window, python-idle

I can't seem to figure out how to zoom in or anything, and the font is so small. Thank you for your help. I'm using a mac if that helps

Comment: Your 'window' tag isn't specific enough to know what you're asking about. If you mean the python IDE, please use the python-idle tag. Otherwise use a tag telling us which tool/platform/whatever your question is about.

Comment: Sorry yes its in Python IDLE.

Answer (score 6):

On the top menu, choose `Options`, then `Configure IDLE`.  The `Fonts/Tabs` tab will be displayed.  There is a `Size` button.  Click on it and select a bigger size than the default of 10.  At present, this only only affects the font in Shell, editor, and output windows, but that is the main issue for me.

EDIT: correct Options menu entry as suggested by Nathan Wailes.  `IDLE Preferences` was once the title of the resulting dialog, but it is now `Settings`.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac Python 3.9, Go to Idle -> Preferences -> Fonts/Tabs Option.

[Screenshot for more clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hhQR.png)